# Failed to deploy visual c++ universal windows app

Tags: visual-studio

This is a blank app created with just default settings (template). Can't find the framework because it has a " \ .\" in the path which should not be there.

Also this is Visual Studio Community 2015.

```
1>------ Deploy started: Project: App1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Updating the layout...
1>Checking whether required frameworks are installed...
1>Framework: Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug/x86, app package version 14.0.23019.0 is not currently installed.
1>Installing missing frameworks...
1>Error : DEP0800 : The required framework "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\14.0\.\AppX\Debug\x86\Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.Debug.14.00.appx" failed to install. 
1>An internal error occurred with error 0x80070005. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Inside this folder there is a file called "SDKManifest.xml" with couple lines as follows
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\14.0\
    AppX-Debug-x86 = ".\AppX\Debug\x86\Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.Debug.14.00.appx"
    AppX-Debug-x64 = ".\AppX\Debug\x64\Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.Debug.14.00.appx"
    AppX-Debug-ARM = ".\AppX\Debug\ARM\Microsoft.VCLibs.ARM.Debug.14.00.appx"
    AppX-Retail-x86 = ".\AppX\Retail\x86\Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.14.00.appx"
    AppX-Retail-x64 = ".\AppX\Retail\x64\Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.appx"
    AppX-Retail-ARM = ".\AppX\Retail\ARM\Microsoft.VCLibs.ARM.14.00.appx"

Edditing out the .\ or just the . doesn't seem to do anything. Still get the error.

Comment: Did you update your visual studio when Windows 10 RTM'd or did you not install Visual Studio until after you installed Windows 10 RTM?

Comment: Installed windows 10 then I downloaded the iso file from Microsoft "vs2015.com_enu.iso".

Comment: Try running VS as admin and then run the app. The internal error is access denied.

Comment: Still get the error when running as admin.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled windows 10, and installed VS from the ISO file I had. No longer get any errors.

The SHA-1 Value for the iso is: BAAD3CEBAB7A5834D8F78F7D02E4880C010F3BA9 which is what [Microsoft](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-iso-sha1-vs.aspx) shows.